# Xamarin.Forms "java.exe" exited with code 1 in debug mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

Installed Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base and Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging and am now getting this error when building the solution. Heap size is 1GB, and from googling everywhere I understand it must be some kind of dependency issue among the nuget packages, however I have no idea how to fix this. Below is a list of my android packages, any more info will be provided if needed, I simply don't know what else you might need, I'm rather new at this.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Make sure that  the `SDK build tool version`  equals `SDK platform`  .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT This is what my SDKs and Tools look like. Thought this meant that they were? I'm new to this, sorry

Comment: It seems has no issue, you could post the issue to https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution on github (thanks to Lucas Zhang for the link).

1: Open the .csproj project file for the Xamarin.Android app project in Visual Studio or another text editor.

2: Find the  tag that contains the  elements for the project, and add the following additional  element to that list:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Guava" ExcludeAssets="all">
  <Version>27.1.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

3: Delete the obj\project.assets.json file and close and reopen the solution to force the NuGet packages to re-restore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Thoft. I tried this with my project and I am still getting the error.  Did you move back to XF 4.8 as well? I can't really do that in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try Cleaning and Building the Solution, it worked for me.

- On Menubar click **Build** -> **Clean solution**.
- After cleaning the solution is completed, run the Project.